# Original source of igu=1 parameter to display google in iframe

Tags: html, google-chrome, iframe

As many on stackoverflow have noticed, using trying to display google in an iframe like this doesn't work:

`<iframe src="https://www.google.com/search?q=query"></iframe>`

However, this does:

`<iframe src="https://www.google.com/search?q=query&igu=1"></iframe>`

Who discovered this? I cannot find the original source.

Comment: I'm also trying to find out myself. what does the "igu" mean? And how would you know to look for this let alone it working?

Comment: My best guess: it means "ignore user", because Google seem to detach the search page from the current logged-in user when this parameter is set. For Google that is a pretty sufficient protection from the risk of embedding the page to design a click jacking attack on Google accounts.

Comment: Google's official statement is this: support.google.com/programmable-search/answer/2631042?hl=en They don't seem interested to suggest this parameter formally.

Answer (score 0):

The discovery of using the "igu=1" parameter to display Google search results in an iframe **is not attributed to a specific individual or source**. It appears to be a **workaround** that was discovered and shared within the developer community to bypass certain restrictions imposed by Google on embedding search results in iframes (using the **[X-Frame-Options header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options)**). Since this workaround is not officially documented by Google, it also means its **long-term reliability and compatibility cannot be guaranteed**.
The "igu" parameter is likely an arbitrary choice made by the developers.

In my opinion, "igu" might stand for *"iFrame Google URL"* or *"iFrame Google Utility"*, but we can't be sure. As @rineez also mentions [on this reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67306800/original-source-of-igu-1-parameter-to-display-google-in-iframe/76575963#comment129310790_67306800), the user is logged out, which could

> [...] mean[s] "ignore user" [...]